# Intellij IDEA java project execute through .bat file

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, intellij-idea, testng

I'm developing a selenium and TestNG project and I want to use Jenkins to run tests from .bat files.

I found some tutorials but all of them using Eclipse IDE. eg: http://learn-automation.com/selenium-integration-with-jenkins/

In Intellij IDEA I couldn't find any lib (jar files) folder and the file structure is slightly different than the Eclipse.

I was able to run through a POM.XML file but I really want to know how to build .bat file to run my testng.xml file. (From the beginning)

Comment: I believe you can move maven call to the bat file and that's it

Comment: can you tell me how to do that ?

Comment: I don't get what you really want to do. If you just want to create a bat file: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/write-simple-batch-bat-file/ . Why do you need Intellij or Eclipse for that? you can use notepad++ for that.

Comment: I have my project in inttelij IDEA. It's a selenium project and execute through testng.xml file. Now I'm integrating the project with jenkins. so I need a batch file to execute build in jenkins.

Comment: bat file with content mvn test ?

Comment: yes, bat file with content of the maven project

Answer (score 0):

Compiling and Running java project from command line without any build automation tools (ANT, Maven, gradle) could get really complicated, however you can do that.

To compile and run I guess following should work.

To compile, I am not sure where class file will be generated but you can check help of javac command.

```
javac -classpath "[jarname with specified path]" [java filename]
```

This will execute the class files.

```
java -cp "path-to-jar/testng.jar:path_to_your_test_classes" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Now you can use this two command in batch file or directly use in jenkins.

However the easy and better approach will be to use Maven. There are lots of online blogs and video tutorial about how to setup up Maven project or convert existing project into maven.

Comment: my project is a maven project.

Comment: then just put this command in your bat file `mvn clean test` and put the file in your project folder and that's it.

Comment: what is mvn clean test ?

Comment: and there is another issue. intellij project folder doesn't contain any jar files for the testng library. also my class files contain in 3 different packages.

Comment: you gotta learn how Maven works. Also it doesn't matter how many packages it has, it has to be handles in TestNG.xml.